# Как определить, установлен ли на телефоне Facebook?

Tags: android, facebook

Как программно определить, установлен ли на телефоне Facebook?
Пытаюсь сделать автоматическую аутентификацию в игрушке через Facebook. Вроде получается, но если Facebook не установлен моё приложение вылетает. Хочу сделать что-бы игра прятала кнопку "Войти через Facebook", если этот Facebook на телефоне не установлен.

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать сделать так: для начала создать `Intent` переменную и в неё поместить новый `Intent` в котором указываете действие как просмотр (`Intent.ACTION_VIEW`) и потом задаю нужный мне пакет приложения с помощью `setPackage(your_package_name)` и потом в `if` проверяю сколько есть пакетов если попытатся выполнить мой `Intent` и если их больше 0 то выполнять код. В вашем случаи код выглядит примерно так:

```
Intent checkFacebookApp = new Intent(ACTION_VIEW).setPackage("com.facebook.orca");

if (getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(checkFacebookApp, 0).size() > 0) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Facebook установлен", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} else {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Facebook не установлен", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```